# SystemModstamp Information

Tags: systemmodstamp

How to know/see the systemModstamp info of a record ? I understand that it is updated through a automated process which is fine but I need to see that info ?

Regards,
Ata.

Comment: It is a field on the record. Have you tried moving that field onto the page layout?

Comment: Thanks Martin - But I don't see that field when I am editing the page layout ?

Answer (score 1):

> SystemModStamp is strictly read-only. Not only is it updated when a
>   user updates the record, but also when automated system processes
>   update the record. Because of this behavior, it creates a difference
>   in stored value where ‘LastModifiedDate <= SystemModStamp’ but never
>   ‘LastModifiedDate > SystemModStamp’.

You can use SystemModStamp in your SOQL query

```
Select Id from Account where SystemModStamp >= 2015-11-19T23:01:01Z
```

Comment: If I have a variable with data type dateTime, can it be used in SOQL condition? For example, 'WHERE SystemModStamp > MyDateTimeVariable'

It is throwing errors and I am unable to figure out why